# $a^2\equiv1 \pmod n$ iff $a\equiv\pm\,1\pmod p$ for all $p\mid n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, prime-factorization

> (Not)if $a$ is an integer and $n$ a postive integer, then
>   $a\equiv\pm 1\pmod p$ for all primes dividing n if and only if 
>   $$a^2\equiv 1\pmod n$$

$\Longrightarrow $ is wrong,Tonyk note count-example $a=4,p=3,n=9$

if $a^2\equiv 1\pmod n,\Longrightarrow (a,n)=1,$,since $p|n$,then we have
$$a^2\equiv 1\pmod p$$then we have
$$a\equiv \pm 1\pmod p?$$

My solution is right? if not,then How prove it?

Comment: This is wrong. Take $n=9$ and $a=4$.

Comment: @TonyK Yes it seems as though throughout his attempt to prove he was juggling an n and a p in the modulus, I just assumed that he meant to have a prime modulus, which is a theorem.

Comment: @Rellek: The question specifically mentions "primes dividing $n$". So $n$ itself obviously doesn't have to be prime.

Comment: Nice,But if $a^2\equiv 1\pmod n$,then $a\equiv \pm1\pmod p?$

Comment: @Australia Yes, of course: that's trivial.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

How about using the definition of modular arithmetic:

Let $p$ be an odd prime.

So, we have $a^2 \equiv 1 \bmod p$. Let's subtract 1, we get: $$a^2-1 \equiv 0 \bmod p$$

We can use the basic rules of factoring here, and the definition of modular arithmetic:

$$p | a^2-1 \implies p | (a-1)(a+1)$$

Now, let us assume that we are dealing with an odd prime p, and it is easy to convince yourself that p cannot divide both $a+1$ and $a-1$, in which case it is one or the other. Either way, you are left with the result:

$$a \equiv \pm 1 \bmod p$$

Comment: It's not clear which direction you are trying to prove here, especially as your conclusion is $p\equiv\pm 1 \mod p$. In any case, the conjecture is false $-$ see my comment to the question.

Comment: I can't see how this helps the OP to answer his question...in particular, how does this help the OP to realize his belief is *wrong*: the claim, as Tony's proved, is wrong.

Comment: Look at his attempt, and check out what letter he is putting in the mod. It goes from n to p. Which one is it? I provided the actual proof for a prime modulus, and it is an iff statement as the converse is trivial to prove. As can easily be seen, this does not hold for a composite modulus.

Comment: This does seem to be the "best-fit" interpretation of the OP - the closest thing to what OP was doing that is actually correct - but it strikes me as strange that OP would accidentally put "for all $p\mid n$" in the title; it's a rather sophisticated typo! I think we should await OP's clarification.